# How do I define my token to pass truffle test?

Tags: solidity, truffle, tokens, erc-20, ethereumjs

After running truffle test i get the following error:

```
Zanes-iMac:xyztoken zanemassey$ truffle test
Using network 'development'.

Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/xyzToken.sol...

Compilation warnings encountered:

/Users/zanemassey/Desktop/xyztoken/contracts/Migrations.sol:11:3: Warning: Defining constructors as functions with the same name as the contract is deprecated. Use "constructor(...) { ... }" instead.
  function Migrations() public {
  ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).
,/Users/zanemassey/Desktop/xyztoken/contracts/xyzToken.sol:8:2: Warning: Defining constructors as functions with the same name as the contract is deprecated. Use "constructor(...) { ... }" instead.
    function xyzToken (uint256 _initialSupply) public {
 ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines).



  Contract: xyzToken
    1) sets the total supply upon deployment
    > No events were emitted


  0 passing (36ms)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: xyzToken
       sets the total supply upon deployment:
     ReferenceError: xyzToken is not defined
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/xyzToken.js:7:3)
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-core/lib/testing/testrunner.js:135:1
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/property.js:119:1
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:89:1
      at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:134:1
      at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:128:1)
      at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:64:1)
      at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:354:1)
      at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:509:1)
      at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/xhr2/lib/xhr2.js:469:1)
      at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1081:12)
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

If no events were emitted then what exactly is it failing?

this is my js:

```
var DappToken = artifacts.require("./xyzToken.sol");

contract('xyzToken', function(accounts) {
    var tokenInstance;

    it('sets the total supply upon deployment', function() {
        return xyzToken.deployed().then(function(instance) {
          tokenInstance = instance;
          return tokenInstance.totalSupply();
        }).then(function(totalSupply) {
          assert.equal(totalSupply.toNumber(), 600000000, 'sets the total supply to 600,000,000');
          return tokenInstance.balanceOf(accounts[0]);
        }).then(function(adminBalance) {
          assert.equal(adminBalance.toNumber(), 600000000, 'it allocates the inital supply to the admin account');
        });
    });
});
```

and solidity:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract xyzToken {
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    function xyzToken (uint256 _initialSupply) public {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = _initialSupply;
        totalSupply = _initialSupply;
    }
}
```

I have asserted total supply for number and admin balance and i have configured ganache accounts with an associative array. What exactly isn't defined about my token?

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

The top line of your javascript is wrong. You've called the artifact `DappToken` but tried to instantiate it with `xyzToken`, which isn't defined, and hence the error you're getting.

Also, consider switching to async/await like the following - it makes the tests much easier on the eyes:

```
const DappToken = artifacts.require("./xyzToken.sol");

contract('xyzToken', accounts => {

  it('sets the total supply upon deployment', async () => {
    const tokenInstance = await DappToken.deployed()
        , initSupply    = 600000000
        , totalSupply   = await tokenInstance.totalSupply()
        , adminBalance  = await tokenInstance.balanceOf(accounts[0])
    assert.equal(totalSupply.toNumber(), initSupply, `Total supply should be ${initSupply}!`)
    assert.equal(adminBalance.toNumber(), initSupply, 'Initial supply should be allocated to admin account!')
  })
})
```